# How to run cron script every hh:29 and hh:59

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am using Google App Engine to run a cron script every 30 minutes. It works well, but it takes a while to finish and I use it in conjunction with a dashboard that also refreshes every 30 minutes, so sometimes the dashboard refreshes before the script has finished and it shows incorrect results.

So I was wondering how I could make the script run at 29 and 59 minutes past the hour so that it would finish in time for the dashboard to load the new data.

E.g. 09:29, 14:59 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
every 30 minutes from 00:29 to 23:59
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run a recurring job at a specific time, but instead only need to run it at regular intervals, use the following notion in your cron.yaml file:

`every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]`

For example, it can be:

```
# cron.yaml
cron:
- description: update dashboard with new information
  url: /tasks/update_dashboard
  schedule: every 30 minutes 23:59 to 23:59
  target: module1
```